# No putRecords method on AmazonKinesisClient

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I'm following the tutorial at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/dev/kinesis-using-sdk-java-add-data-to-stream.html - translating the PutRecords example fom java to scala.

I've included `amazon-kinesis-client v1.20` and `aws-java-sdk-kinesis v1.9.16` as dependencies.

Compiling using sbt gives me the following error:

`value putRecords is not a member of com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient`

Experimenting using the console confirms that this method does not seem to exist on the version of AmazonKinesisClient included with these libraries. Has anyone else had this problem and does anyone know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

The method appears to exist in the aws-java-sdk-kinesis 1.9.16 JAR currently available through [Maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-kinesis/1.9.16):

```
$ javap -cp aws-java-sdk-kinesis-1.9.16.jar com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient | grep PutRecords
  public com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.PutRecordsResult putRecords(com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.PutRecordsRequest);
```

Is it possible that your IDE or classpath contains a reference to another (older) version of the Kinesis or AWS SDKs?